# Как сделать так, чтобы персонаж мог передвигать предметы в Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно сделать так, чтобы персонаж мог передвигать предметы с Box Collider 2D в Uniy 2D, то есть игрок подходит сбоку к "Коробке", нажимает на кнопу, после чего персонаж двигается вместе с этим предметом.
Я не нашёл ничего похожего в открытом доступе, возможно плохо искал. Сам я новичок и в Unity, и в C#, поэтому если не сложно, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать передвижение предметов.
Заранее спасибо.
Вот код передвижения персонажа:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float groundRadius;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    public float jumpForce;
    
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Animator animWalk, animJump;
    private bool isGround;
    private float x;
    
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        animWalk = GetComponent<Animator>();
        animJump = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Move();
        PickUp();
    }
    
    void Move()
    {
        isGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, groundMask);
        
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
        
        
        if (!isGround)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        else if (isGround)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(x, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGround)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce);
        }
        
        if (!isGround)
        {
            animJump.SetBool("IsJump", true);
        }
        else
        {
            animJump.SetBool("IsJump", false);
        }
        
        if (x != 0)
        {
            animWalk.SetBool("IsWalk", true);
        }
        else
        {
            animWalk.SetBool("IsWalk", false);
        }
        
        if (x < 0 && isGround)
        {
            rb.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
        }
        else if (x > 0 && isGround)
        {
            rb.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    
    private bool isPickup;
    private float distance = 1f;
    RaycastHit2D hit;
    
    void PickUp()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            if (!isPickup)
            {
                Physics2D.queriesStartInColliders = false;
                hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.right * transform.localScale.x, distance);
                
                if (hit.collider != null);
                {
                    isPickup = true;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if (isPickup)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите код, который отвечает у Вас за движение персонажа и обработку входа в коллайдер.

Comment: Добавил код в основной вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Делайте рейкаст из головы игрока и ограничьте ему длину, что бы игрок не мог брать объекты, которые находятся слишком далеко. Проверяйте если рейкаст попал в объект с тегом pickupable_item, который надо добавить всем предметам, которые можно поднять, то надо проверяйте нажата ли кнопка, если да то делаем предмет ребёнком игрока.

По желанию в скрипте игрока можете добавить перемещение объекта при повороте.

Answer (score 0):

Хочу добавить к ответу farkon00,
Если хотите чтобы предмет ещё плавно двигался как в Амнезии, например, можно сделать Empty GameObject ребёнком тела игрока, назвав его, например, hand и воспользоваться интерполяцией (Vector2.Lerp):

```
bool characterGrabItem = false;
float itemMovementSpeed = 3.0f;
Transform? item;

// Вызывайте, когда нажимаете на кнопку действия (берёте предмет или бросаете его)
void GrabItem()
{
   
if(characterGrabItem)
{
// Если персонаж держит предмет - сбросить его. И там ниже ещё стейт меняется.
    item = null;
}
else
{
    // Здесь рейкаст и TryGetComponent и назначайте трансформ 
    //компонента в item, или если ничего не нашли рейкастом - return;
    //...
}
  // переключение состояния удержания предмета.
   characterGrabItem = !characterGrabItem;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
   if (item is not null && characterGrabItem){ 
      item.position = Vector2.Lerp(item.position, hand.position, itemMovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
   }
}
// Ну и чутка доработать можно и со значениями поиграться чтобы коллизию не ломать.
```

Comment: А если у предмета есть Rigidbody2D, то можно заменить тип item на Rigidbody2D и у TryGetComponent искать Rigidbody2D, а затем заменить 
if (item is not null && characterGrabItem){ 
      item.position = Vector2.Lerp(item.position, hand.position, itemMovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
   }
на 
if (item is not null && characterGrabItem){ 
     item.MovePosition(Vector2.Lerp(item.position, hand.position, itemMovementSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
   }

Тогда предмет будет меньше застревать в коллайдерах.